# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Direct buffer memory ERROR while listening kafka topics, Spring kafka consumers

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, apache-kafka

Following are the properties used to create consumer:

```
Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServers);
props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, KafkaAvroDeserializer.class);
props.put(KafkaAvroSerializerConfig.VALUE_SUBJECT_NAME_STRATEGY,
TopicRecordNameStrategy.class.getName());
props.put("schema.registry.url", schemaRegistryUrl);
props.put(ConsumerConfig.ALLOW_AUTO_CREATE_TOPICS_CONFIG, true);
props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, groipId);
props.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, false);
props.put(ConsumerConfig.PARTITION_ASSIGNMENT_STRATEGY_CONFIG,
"org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.RoundRobinAssignor");
props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");
```

```
> java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space 2020-11-05 12:07:31,002
> ERROR [consumer-10-C-1] [] org.springframework.core.log.LogAccessor:
> Stopping container due to an Error java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java
> heap space 2020-11-05 12:07:30,999 ERROR [consumer-5-C-1] []
> org.springframework.core.log.LogAccessor: Stopping container due to an
> Error java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space     at
> java.base/java.nio.HeapByteBuffer.<init>(Unknown Source)  at
> java.base/java.nio.ByteBuffer.allocate(Unknown Source)    at
> org.apache.kafka.common.memory.MemoryPool$1.tryAllocate(MemoryPool.java:30)
>   at
> org.apache.kafka.common.network.NetworkReceive.readFrom(NetworkReceive.java:113)
>   at
> org.apache.kafka.common.network.KafkaChannel.receive(KafkaChannel.java:447)
>   at
> org.apache.kafka.common.network.KafkaChannel.read(KafkaChannel.java:397)
>   at
> org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.attemptRead(Selector.java:678)
>   at
> org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.pollSelectionKeys(Selector.java:580)
>   at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.poll(Selector.java:485)
>   at
> org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.poll(NetworkClient.java:550)
>   at
> org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.poll(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:262)
>   at
> org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.poll(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:233)
>   at
> org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.poll(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:212)
>   at
> org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator.ensureCoordinatorReady(AbstractCoordinator.java:236)
>   at
> org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator.poll(ConsumerCoordinator.java:469)
>   at
> org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.updateAssignmentMetadataIfNeeded(KafkaConsumer.java:1274)
>   at
> org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:1238)
>   at
> org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:1173)
>   at brave.kafka.clients.TracingConsumer.poll(TracingConsumer.java:89)
>   at brave.kafka.clients.TracingConsumer.poll(TracingConsumer.java:83)
>   at
> org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doPoll(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1109)
>   at
> org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.pollAndInvoke(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1065)
>   at
> org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.run(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:990)
>   at
> java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown
> Source)   at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown
> Source)   at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
> 
> 
> 2020-11-05 12:07:31,276 ERROR [consumer-5-C-1] []
> org.springframework.core.log.LogAccessor: Stopping container due to an
> Error java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Direct buffer memory    at
> java.base/java.nio.Bits.reserveMemory(Unknown Source)     at
> java.base/java.nio.DirectByteBuffer.<init>(Unknown Source)    at
> java.base/java.nio.ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(Unknown Source)  at
> java.base/sun.nio.ch.Util.getTemporaryDirectBuffer(Unknown Source)    at
> java.base/sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(Unknown Source)  at
> java.base/sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(Unknown Source)  at
> java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(Unknown Source)   at
> org.apache.kafka.common.network.PlaintextTransportLayer.read(PlaintextTransportLayer.java:103)
>   at
> org.apache.kafka.common.network.NetworkReceive.readFrom(NetworkReceive.java:118)
>   at
> org.apache.kafka.common.network.KafkaChannel.receive(KafkaChannel.java:447)
>   at
> org.apache.kafka.common.network.KafkaChannel.read(KafkaChannel.java:397)
>   at
> org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.attemptRead(Selector.java:678)
>   at
> org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.pollSelectionKeys(Selector.java:580)
>   at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.poll(Selector.java:485)
>   at
> org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.poll(NetworkClient.java:550)
>   at
> org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.poll(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:262)
>   at
> org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.poll(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:233)
>   at
> org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.poll(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:212)
>   at
> org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator.ensureCoordinatorReady(AbstractCoordinator.java:236)
>   at
> org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator.poll(ConsumerCoordinator.java:469)
>   at
> org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.updateAssignmentMetadataIfNeeded(KafkaConsumer.java:1274)
>   at
> org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:1238)
>   at
> org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:1173)
>   at brave.kafka.clients.TracingConsumer.poll(TracingConsumer.java:89)
```

Comment: Simply showing the properties isn't going to solve an OOM. Something in your consumer logic would likely cause that. Otherwise, what is your current heap size and what efforts have you made to increase it?

Comment: So we have 2 environment with same memory configurations, it is working fine one sone environment and facing issue in other environment. only difference in the environment is security protocol. Not working where the security protocol is SSL.

Comment: If you didn't have SSL enabled, you should have been getting an SSL handshake error, not OOM, but again, its unclear what your initial heap sizes were

Comment: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-4090

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Added consumer property props.put("security.protocol", "SSL");
Worked

Comment: Connecting to SSL enabled kafka server without SSL enabled in consumer configs or misconfiguration of SSL configs is the problem.